# Is there a way to uniquely identify the website (or application) hosted in IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, licensing, piracy

Is there a way to uniquely identify the website (or application) hosted in IIS? For example, if I'm hosting a website to a customer in his/her server with limited license, I don't want him to copy the same site and host in the same server and provide for other users.

I'm planning to restrict the copying the site another server by binding the mac (physical) address of the server.

Comment: Binding to the mac address will not help because 1) it can be spoofed + 2) you can easily run multiple websites on one mac if you just want to host multiple instances (instead of copying to a new machine)

Comment: Maybe consider creating a license based on the website's [IIS Metabase ID](https://forums.iis.net/t/1185896.aspx) instead.